# Anonymising customer ID in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a CSV file with about 200k rows. The first column contains `customer_id`. This id could be used to track back to a specific identifiable customer, so I'd like to replace these values with an random id instead. The same customer can appear on numerous rows in the table.  Customer ids vary in length

```
customer_id l4_id   sales   items   baskets
  123456    F38C    15.11   2       2
  123456    F15C    11      7       4
  123456    F16C    13.15   7       4
  123456    F35A    7.3     3       1
  123456    F13A    3.1     3       3
  123456    F02F    1.6     1       1
  123456    F04C    11.8    8       4
  123456    F06C    18.43   7       4
23456789    F38C    20      6       2
23456789    F06C    8.2     5       1
```

How can I add a new column, `random_id`, with a random number which links to the `customer_id`?  I need to be able to aggregate the data using the `random_id`.

I've looked, but can't find a solution for my particular problem.

Expected result will be a new column with a new numeric id.  Bonus if this can be a 6 digit number, but single digit number would also be sufficient.

```
customer_id l4_id   sales   items   baskets random_id
  123456    F38C    15.11   2       2       100000
  123456    F15C    11      7       4       100000
  123456    F16C    13.15   7       4       100000
  123456    F35A    7.3     3       1       100000
  123456    F13A    3.1     3       3       100000
  123456    F02F    1.6     1       1       100000
  123456    F04C    11.8    8       4       100000
  123456    F06C    18.43   7       4       100000
23456789    F38C    20      6       2       100001
23456789    F06C    8.2     5       1       100001
```

Comment: This looks like do-it-for-me-for-free kind of question.

Comment: If you add a new random ID to the table you can still reference to the customer ID. You will have to store the data without any link to the original customer to anonymize it.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question, but what's stopping you from assigning a new ID to each `customer_id` (in sorted order), starting at 100000? This would not 'anonimise' anything, as there would still be a one-to-one correspondence, however.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this, so I probably haven't explained myself very well.
Once I've added a new random_id column, which contained a number that wouldn't trace back to an identifiable customer, I would save a new table which dropped the customer_id.

Comment: @N.Wouda I think that would work, but I can't even work out how to do that at the moment.

Comment: M_keo, everyone is a beginner at some point - but I would recommend simply looking up how to generate a random 6-digit number, or 6-character code, and then looping that. Then look up `pandas.series.map` and assign each ID to a new random code.

Answer (score 1):

```
# create dictionary with new random 6 digit ids
import random
dictionary = dict(zip(
    set(df.customer_id), 
    list(set([random.randrange(10**5,10**6) for a in np.arange(len(set(df.customer_id))*1.3)]))[:len(set(df.customer_id))]))

# now we will match the old ids from the dataset to the new ones
df.new_id = df['customer_id'].map(dictionary)
```

Comment: Why not simply `for a in len(set(df.customer_id))` ?

Comment: Since we use random id, it may appear to have duplicated values. Therefore, I calculated the number of unique ids (let it be x ids), and generated 1.3*x of random ids, and took the only x of them. That trick is necessary to guarantee uniqueness of new id.

Comment: `random.seed(5)`  `[len(set([random.randrange(10**5,10**6) for a in np.arange(1000)])) for a in np.arange(10)]`    `[1000, 999, 1000, 999, 1000, 999, 1000, 1000, 999, 999]`

Even for a small database of 1000 records, random generator gave 5 times 999 unique values

Comment: Oh - so you use `set` and assume that there will be enough unique values, and `dict(zip())` uses the length of the shortest group. Thanks for explaining :)